# Error while installing railsinstaller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railsinstaller

I downloaded railsinstaller 2.1 on my PC. Every time I try to install it I get

```
Error 5: access denied.
Setup was unable to create directory "C:\Sites\todo"
```

Since it's giving me an access denied error, I should run the installer as administrator. Right? But I get the error either way.

Answer (score 0):

That's very odd, right click the todo folder and select properties then click the security tab and verify that administrators have full control of that folder?

You could also try creating the folder first then running it, although it'll probably do the same when creating sub directories.